# Problem integrate a vue.js frontend with my django backend

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

I have a problem with integratinga vue.js frontend with my Django backend.

I use webpack loader to insert my vue.js web-pack-stats into my Django template, but I get the following error and I don't understand why:

my Vue.config.js

```
     const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");
        const webpack = require('webpack');
        //const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

        // Change this to match the path to your files in production (could be S3, CloudFront, etc.)
        const DEPLOYMENT_PATH = '/static/dist/'


        module.exports = {
            // on Windows you might want to set publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" 
            publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? DEPLOYMENT_PATH : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
            outputDir: '../CodeGeniusERP/static/dist',


            devServer: {
                public: 'localhost:8080',
                headers: {`enter code here`
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                },
            },


            configureWebpack: {
                // Set up all the aliases we use in our app.
                plugins: [
                    new BundleTracker({ path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json' }),
                    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
                        maxChunks: 6
                    })
                ]
            },
            pwa: {
                name: 'Vue Argon Dashboard',
                themeColor: '#172b4d',
                msTileColor: '#172b4d',
                appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
                appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: '#172b4d'
            },
            css: {
                // Enable CSS source maps.
                sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
            }
        };
```

Django settings.py:

```
    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'dd7mv&64-oucgl4_ok1&7f#nr01z2w^5-sxm6l%!&+hu2i+ki#'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.sites',

        'ERP',
        'users',

        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',

        'rest_auth',
        'rest_auth.registration',

        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',

        'crispy_forms',
        'webpack_loader',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'CodeGeniusERP.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CodeGeniusERP.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True

    LOGIN_URL = "accounts/login/"
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    #   Custom User Model
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"

    #   django-crispy-forms
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

    #   django.contrib.sites
    SITE_ID = 1

    #   django-allauth
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"

    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = (True)

    #   Django-REST-Framework
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',     
        ),
          'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
          ),
          'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
          'PAGE_SIZE': 2
    }


    WEBPACK_LOADER =  {
        'DEFAULT':{
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'dist/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vue-argon-dashboard-master', 'webpack-stats.json'),
        }
    }
```

The error message I get from Django:

[Django ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fKxN.png)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks alot!

Comment: probably something not configured correctly, but it's hard to figure out what. You should scroll down your error trace, finding the line where the error is produced (webpack_loader/loader.py line 43) and open the "local vars" pane for each line in the call stack, starting at the bottom and moving up, trying to figure out where the wrong value comes from. The error is probably in `chunk['name']` and `chunk` is a string instead of a dictionary for some reason. Following the stack up might give a clue.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,
I tried to figure out the error, but I was not able to figure out, what the cause of the error  is. I'm going crazy

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

It was a problem with the version of webpack-bundle-tracker

To fix the problem just (in the Frontend Folder):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
```